# how to detect a parabola using hough transformation in python

Tags: python, detection, hough-transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlSy.png)i am trying to detect the parabola in this image,please help how to do it
my equation is y= ax**2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSnQB.png)